# Sum value to previous value in array

Tags: c#, arrays

What I'm doing wrong? What I'm trying to do is to add to existing array `linesLat` values but for next value to insert in `linesLat` is to take previous from array and summ `stepLong`. But at the end getting error.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stepLong = (10.6237 - 5.9216) / 1000;
        var stepLat = (47.7245 - 45.7368) / 1000;

        double[] linesLat = { 45.7368 };
        double[] linesLong = { 5.9216 };

        for (var i = 1; i <= 999; )
        {
            linesLat[i] = linesLat[i - 1] + stepLat; // throws an error
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: upvoting because people are downvoting without a comment and because I genuinely can't see anything wrong with this question

Comment: You really better take a look in some basic C# tutorial about arrays, it would save you lots of grief and time in the future, and the need to ask super trivial questions here.

Comment: @Paul too bad, because of such actions Stack Overflow might end up like Yahoo Answers. This is NOT a tutorial. People are expected to come with at least some basic knowledge about what they are doing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm with Paul on this--it's a basic question, sure, and it's easy for us to see what's wrong, but that just means it's well-written. I see code, a verbatim error message, and commentary on what he expects to happen. Unless it's a duplicate (which it probably is, but I haven't checked yet), I don't see any major issues.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen your call, but I won't change my mind. Such questions have no quality whatsoever -they are just trivial mistakes that should be done as part of the initial learning.

Comment: @John Just by the way, I wasn't sure if this was just a simplification for asking the question or not, but unless you're doing something really wonky (which you aren't here), it's generally best to include the `i++` in the last clause of the `for`: `for (var i = 1; i <= 999; i++)`, then you'll just have one line in the loop itself. They'll function the same way, but that'll make more readable code. If it's in the `for` line, it still won't get called until after the loop executes once.

Comment: @Matthew trying a different angle now. The actual question here got nothing to do with sum, it's just "Why am I getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error. And the answer is as plain as "because the index is bigger than the array length". It's not basic, it's trivial - there's a difference. Not expecting to convince you, just sharing my opinion.

Comment: I got it now, I looked at the basics, but somehow I didn't get the idea from examples, but was more driven by my logic, which maybe wasn't good. And thanks for those who got the idea and what I'm trying to do, next time I will try to explain myself more clearly.

Comment: @John, Added another "Possible solution section".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really go back to basics.

Array as a limited size and it will be on the exact size you declare it to be.
In your case you allocated two arrays in the size of 1 (Due to explicit initialization).

```
double[] linesLat = { 45.7368 }; // Size 1
double[] linesLong = { 5.9216 }; // Size 1
```

**Meaning** you can't loop from [0, 999], when you will try to take the value from position 1 (Because C# arrays are zero based; The first element is in the 0 place and not 1) you will get a **KABOOM** meaning you will get an exception telling you, your index (probably 1) is outside of the legal array bounds.

**Solution:** You should change your solution to declare a bigger array as @i_a_joref suggested.

```
var linesLat = new double[1000];
linesLat[0] = 45.7368;
```

**Additionally**, your loop can be written more properly:

```
for (var i = 1; i < linesLat.Length; i++)
{
    linesLat[i] = linesLat[i - 1] + stepLat;
}
```

**Possible solution variation for your problem.**

If the only goal is to get the sum of the last formula, than array is redundant.

```
double sumOfFormula = 45.7368;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) // Will run [0, 999] 1000 iterations
{
    sumOfFormula += stepLat;
}
Console.WriteLine("Sum: ", sumOfFormula);
```

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, Haven't noticed that, thank you for the remark.

Comment: Thanks, adding another insight for the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You declared `linesLat` as an array of size one.  If you want to put 999+ elements in it, you need to declare a bigger array.

Answer (score 3):

Your array has a lenght of 1, and you try to iterate up to 999.

You need to instanciate your array with a lengh of 999

```
 double[] linesLat = new double[999];
```

Answer (score 3):

Your array have size of 1 and in for loop you are trying to access indexes greater then array size.
Just change:

```
double[] linesLat = { 45.7368 };
```

to:

```
double[] linesLat = new double[1000];
linesLat[0] = 45.7368;
```